# Basic Matrix Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know its basic but I am not quite getting it. I have two matrices W and U. W has 3M rows and M columns while U is M into M diagonal matrix. I want to ask if R1 and R2 are equivalent. If yes then why?

$R1=W^{T} U^{-1}W$

$R2=W^{T} W U^{-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To multiply $W^T$ by $U^{-1}$, the number of columns of $W^T$ must equal the number of rows of $U^{-1}$.  But this is not the case ($W^T$ has $3M$ columns and $U^{-1}$ has $M$ rows), so $R_1$ is not defined.

However $R_2=W^TWU^{-1}$ is defined, and will be an $M$ by $M$ matrix, provided that the diagonal entries of $U$ are not zero.  (If any diagonal entry is zero then $U^{-1}$ does not exist.)